# IOS warning: instance method 'userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)' nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

In an iOS project, I have implemented the following delegate method to handle Notifications when app is in foregorund:

```
func userNotificationCenter (_ pNotificationCenter : UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent pNotification : UNNotification, withCompletionHandler pCompletionHandler : @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) -> Void
{
    // When app is in foreground, notification is directly sent to 
    // the app by invoking this delegate method. 
}
```

Usually, this warning means a simple spelling error which causes the compiler to get confused with the method specification in protocol. But I've verified all that from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter).

Out of curiosity, I wanted to check what Xcode suggests... and it's the following delegate method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
}
```

Notice the `Int` parameter in the escaping closure. But this is wrong, right? The Apple documentation (linked above) explicitly states the escaping closure's parameter is `UNNotificationPresentationOptions`. And `UNNotificationPresentationOptions` is not an enum (it's a struct), so the closure cannot take `Int`, yet Xcode suggested it.

Xcode also gave the following suggestion:

```
Make 'userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)' private to silence this warning
```

but why? I have implemented the right delegate method. How can I fix this warning?

**Edit1:**
Here's a [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Mrf_eSjDn6JK07L999V3eZ2xQz2nijZ/view?usp=share_link) which has a tiny version of the Xcode project I'm working on. After downloading the zip file, please follow the steps to setup and reproduce the warning:

1. Download the zip file
2. Unzip the file and place its contents (2 folders - SampleBuilds & SampleWorkspace) in /tmp folder of your Mac (this is to prevent errors due to difference in paths if placed in home folder).
3. Now, navigate to SampleBuilds->SampleWorkspace->TWInt->IOS_Simulator-arm64
4. Open SampleProject.xcodeproj
5. Clean (Cmd + Shift + K) and Build (Cmd + B) the SampleApp target. (When building multiple times, the warning may not appear. Always clean and build)

Comment: is this `func userNotificationCenter (_ pNotificationCenter : UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent pNotification : UNNotification, withCompletionHandler /CompletionHandler : @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) -> Void
` a delegate method ? from where?

Comment: UNNotificationPresentationOptions is enum of options and represented by NSUInteger. Look at UNNotificationPresentationOptions.h. It's just Swift converting them to structs with single rawValue field when importing.

Comment: You have `withCompletionHandler /CompletionHandler` in your code. What is with the `/C`? Is that a typo in your question or your actual code? I copied your code and I get the same error. If I then fix the `/C` and change it to just `c` then the error is resolved.

Comment: @HangarRash, mb, that was a typo in the source (from where I copied and pasted here). And that typo was due me to trying to resolve the warning.. I stashed all my attempts and updated the question with the original code. I still get this warning.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, That delegate method is from `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD The fixed code in your question does not give me any errors or warnings. What version of Xcode are you using? What is your project's deployment target?

Comment: Also, what version of Swift is selected for the target?

Comment: @HangarRash, Xcode - 15.2, Deployment - iOS 14.0.

Comment: @benc, Swift 5.0

Comment: @NightFuryLxD I set my test project to have a deployment target of iOS 14.0 and I still see no error with your code. Try doing a clean build, restart Xcode. Any better?

Comment: @HangarRash, I deleted the entire project and generated it again (I'm using CMake to create the Xcode project)... Still same warning. Instead of using CMake, I created an independent Xcode project in a different mac and added Notification related code.. I'm not getting any warnings there :(.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD Then clearly the issue is with how you are building with CMake. Update your question with all relevant details.

Comment: @HangarRash, When I change the completion handler from `(UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)` to `(Int) -> Void`, the warning disappears.   But I don't understand why? `UNNotificationPresetnationOptions` (which has an int inside) is a struct.. Idk how Xcode is suggesting to use `Int` instead of that struct. Why? Am I missing something basic?

Comment: @NightFuryLxD As I said, I don't see any errors in Xcode with your code. There simply isn't enough detail in your question to know why you are seeing the error.

Comment: @HangarRash, I've attached an Xcode project which reproduces this warning. I've updated the question. Please follow those steps to setup and reproduce.